# How to include multiple condition for intellij goland file mask?

Tags: intellij-idea, goland

I  use strings like `!*main*.js` to filter out some files. But what if on top of this, I need the files to have 'test' in the file name?
I tried the following but they won't work:

`!*main*.js & *test*`

`!*main*.js && *test*`

`!*main*.js AND *test*`

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use comma to separate conditions:

```
!*main*.js,*test*
```

Alternatively, you can use Scopes: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html

Answer (score 0):

May not be relevant here but did this wonder wonder for me.
Additionally, you can combine different conditions like this *.java,!*Test.java -> That is present in *.java files and do not include search from *Test.java files